# Придаточные образа действия - индикатив / сослагательное наклонение

Tags: наклонение, сослагательное

Пара примеров из анализа (в оригинале стоит всегда сослаг.накл.):

(1) *Однако он не мог выказать своего отношения, **как хотел бы**, ибо сердце сыграло с ним злую шутку.*

(2) *Он ждал этого дня, **как никто на свете не мог бы ждать ничего и никого**: ни на миг не падая духом.*

Я не эксперт, но как мне кажется можно легко "вынуть" частицу *бы* из контекста и предложения не сильно искажаются. 
Но хорошо, для достижения эффекта потенциальности и нереальности оставим их...

(3) *И в конце концов он вошел в ее мысли так, **как она и представить себе не могла**.*

Если она это не могла представить себе, значит действие ирреальное, не имевшее еще место, не так ли? 
Как тогда объяснить индикатив?!?

Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: ребята, еще вопрос: как можно обосновать тот факт, что от частицы БЫ можно так легко избавится в предложениях (1) и (2)?

Answer (score 1):

1 и 2. Да, можно выкинуть.

> > Если она это не могла представить себе, значит действие ирреальное

Вовсе нет. Я не представляю, как можно бежать стометровку быстрее 10 секунд, но ведь бегают?

Answer (score 1):

В примере 1,2, частицу **бы** можно опустить. В последнем примере речь идет о определенном промежутке времени в прошлом: имеется в виду, до этого ей в голову не приходили мысли об этом. А вот если здесь поставить частицу **бы** , тогда уже действие будет мыслится как гипотетическое.